# use local png map tiles for leaflet

Tags: javascript, web, maps, leaflet, offline

Writing path of local png files for showing them as map

gives error not found if:

`var cloudmade = L.tileLayer('map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')`

gives error not allowed to load local resource if:

 `var cloudmade = L.tileLayer('file:///D:/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png');`

By the way without local file all works fine. I think that problem in path that I give.

Comment: Are you using Linux or Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Permissions would be the problem, if the file can be seen given the path.

Answer (score 0):

I find the problem...It was in the Eclipse... it does not update statcic path to new files, so it didn't see tiles, to solve it i had to refresh them manually... and re-index all files in the project.